# AuthorizeRouteView Authorizing and NotAuthorized parameters settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I wanted to use the `NotAuthorized` attribute in the `<AuthorizeRouteView>` tag to redirect to the login page every time a non logged-in user try to access a page.

Howewer, it requires a `RenderFragment<AuthentificationState>` typed parameter. What shoud I put to set this parameter to render the login page ?

**Edit :** Code is pretty simple. I used the Blazor server side project template with identity stored in application, just added the `RedirectToLogin.razor` like this :

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@code { 
    protected override void OnAfterRender()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("counter"); //for an unknown reason, the "Identity/Account/Login" redirect doesn't work.
    }
}
```

And modified the `App.razor` :

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if(true) { } //Used for breakpoint.
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    @if(true) { } //Used for breakpoint.
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

I didn't touch the `Startup.cs` so it look like this :

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I always get an error when I try to use the NavigationManager in OnInitialised(), so I can only use it in OnAfterRender. I'm using .Net Core 3.0 by the way, And even like this, it never enter into any of the 2 authorization tags possible, I checked with my `if(true) { }` statements. Else it considers directly the user to be authorized even without being identified or it don't even care about those tags.

Comment: Did you try to upgrade to 3.1-preview3 ?

Comment: Do you have an `<AuthorizedView>` or a `AuthorizeAttribute` in your main layout ?

Comment: You need this: NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Identity/Account/Login", forceLoad:true); See my answer.

Comment: @aguafrommars No but does that change anything ? Shouldn't the redirect trigger before the routing by checking if the user is authorized ? And I won't upgrade to a preview for now unless utmost necessary as the app is supposed to be on market. (Sorry for late anwers, wasn't on my computer on the weekend)

Comment: @aguafrommars The solution of putting `AuthorizedView` in the main layout is working. I'll take this as the solution as there is really no way of making this work through `<AuthorizeRouteView>`. If you could specify which version of .Net you are using where the wanted method work so I could test with the previews, it would be great.

Comment: @PepperTigerI use the latest : 3.1-preview3

Answer (score 17):

I struggled with a similar issue where my `<NotAuthorized>` part in app.razor was not being displayed for a user that was not authorized. After 3 days of pulling my hair out, I also was going for the solution in the MainLayout.razor as mentioned in other answers. One last attempt with a clean project, made my aware of how poor a programmer I am because I finally found the answer.

I did not read the documentation entirely, in which I could find the cause of the problem. On the following page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#customize-unauthorized-content-with-the-router-component
you find how the NotAuthorized part is invoked. I totally missed the second bullet point:

> The Router component, in conjunction with the AuthorizeRouteView
> component, allows the app to specify custom content if:
>
> - Content isn't found.
> - ***The user fails an [Authorize] condition applied to the component. The [Authorize] attribute is covered in the [Authorize] attribute
>   section.***
> - Asynchronous authentication is in progress.

This means the `<NotAuthorized>` part is only invoked/displayed when the route endpoint has a Authorize tag. In my case the route was going to my index page, without an Authorize tag....

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to MartinH, I did not spend 3 days pulling my hair out.

For anyone else requiring clarification on the 'Authorize attrtibute', here's an example...

**VerifyAuth.razor**

```
@page "/verifyauth"
@attribute [Authorize]    @*<--RIGHT HERE!!!*@

<div class="container">

    <h3 class="text-center">Verify Auth</h3>

</div>

@code {

}
```

**App.razor**

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" >
            <Authorizing>
                <text>Please wait, we are authorizing you...</text>
            </Authorizing>
            <NotAuthorized>
                @if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
                {
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                }
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <CascadingAuthenticationState>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there is nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </CascadingAuthenticationState>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

**RedirectToLogin.razor**

```
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/login");
    }
}
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#customize-unauthorized-content-with-the-router-component

Answer (score 1):

`RenderFragment<AuthentificationState>` is piece of html to render.
You should create a component redirecting to the login:

**ReditectToLogin.razor**

```cs
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager

@code {
    protected override Initialized()
    {
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo("login");
    }
}
```

**App.razor**

```html
...
<AuthorizeRouteView>
...
    <NotAuthorized>
       <ReditectToLogin />
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeRouteView>
```

**MainLayout.razor**

```html
<div class="sidebar bg-light">
    <NavMenu />
</div>

<div class="main bg-light mb-2">
...
    <div class="content px-4">
        <AuthorizeView>
            <Authorized>
                @Body
            </Authorized>
        </AuthorizeView>
```

Comment: It won't work, already tried it. It never goes inside any of the authorization tags. And you can't use `NavigationManager` inside `OnInitialized`, it throws an error. You should put it in `OnAfterRender`

Comment: What if you just write a message in `NotAuthorized` ? that doesn't display anything ?

Comment: I'm don't have the project anymore under my eyes but I tried it and I remember not seeing anything. I checked also by putting an `if(true) { }` statement and putting a breakpoint into it but it's never reached. The only way I found efficient is to use `<AuthorizeView>` inside every page and component but as it's always the same pattern, it's a bit tedious.

Comment: Looks weird, that means you authorize everything then. I use policies and it work well. You can browse the code [here](https://github.com/aguacongas/TheIdServer/tree/master/src/Aguacongas.TheIdServer.BlazorApp)

Comment: I used the template with indentity included in the app, and wrote the exact same code as you. I'll try again now on another PC and tell you the outcome.

Comment: Nope, still not working. Not even in `<Authorizing>`

Comment: @ agua from mars, he needs to call NavigateTo like this:   NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Identity/Account/Login", forceLoad:true); with a second parameter set to true to force navigation to "Identity/Account/Login", which is not part of the Blazor Server app. He also needs to apply the Authorize attribute to the component Page he wants to authorize. See my answer. It works for me, and that is the way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

I have used a RedirectToLogin component as detailed above, but I got it working only after I made the following changes :

**Mainlayout.Razor**, I had to insert a using at the top so that the Redirect Component can be used :

```
@using MyBlazorApp.Pages
        <AuthorizeView>
            <Authorized>
                @* code omitted for brevity *@
            </Authorized>
            <NotAuthorized>
                <RedirectToLogin />
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeView>
```

I had to do the following in **RedirectToLogin**

```
@inject NavigationManager nav
@code {
        protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
            nav.NavigateTo("/login");
            return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
        }
    }
```

... and finally, here's **App.razor**

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <CascadingAuthenticationState>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">

                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </CascadingAuthenticationState>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Comment: Yeah I ended up putting my `<RedirectToLogin>` into `MainLayout.razor` instead of `App.razor` too. It's the only way for it to work. If you detail your answer before I do (don't have so much time right now to do it), I'll be glad to upvote it and mark it as the answer.

Comment: I'm relatively new here so not sure what you mean by "detail your answer", but I've posted a bit more detail in my answer above. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you don't need to define an additional RedirectToLogin component at all. You can completely implement this in the OnInitialized of the Login component. Doesn't it look more elegant?

App.Razor:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <Login />
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Login Component:

```
@page "/login"
@layout NullLayout
@inject NavigationManager nav
<h3>Login</h3>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        if (nav.Uri != $"{nav.BaseUri}login")
        {
            nav.NavigateTo("/login");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add to your file .csproj the item pour use this library

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization" Version="x.x.x" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

in program app.cs

```
<Found Context="routeData">
   <AuthorizeRouteView  RouteData="@routeData" 
    DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
     <Authorizing>
      <text> Your text.</text>
     </Authorizing>
...
</Found>
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?