# Blazor - one page without authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, openid-connect

My Blazor app works correctly with OIDC (AzureAD) authentication, however it always requires this for any page of the application. In other words, if the user is not signed in, every page auto redirects to the Oauth2 sign-in, and then back again once the user has signed in.

I would like to have one "signed out" page that has a sign-in button and does not require a signed-in user but cannot find a way to do this. I have tried the following "blank" page:

```
@page "/"
@layout LayoutEmpty
@attribute [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AllowAnonymous]

Foo
```

and `LayoutEmpty.razor`:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<div class="main">    
    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

The code in `Program.cs` is (I have omitted some lines not relevant to authentication, for brevity):

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => { options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy; });
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();   
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
app.Run();
```

However, launching this still goes straight to the Oauth2 process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using`builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => { options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy; });`
By default,the `DefaultPolicy` is to configure global authorize for all pages.
You could just use `builder.Services.AddAuthorization()` and use `@attribute [Authorize]` for pages you need.
The `DefaultPolicy` can also be override such as

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
     //It is also possible to filter the page route via context
    options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policy =>
           policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                      context.User.Identity?.Name?.Equals("Tom") ?? false));

     //override "Defaultpolicy"
    options.DefaultPolicy = options.GetPolicy("MyPolicy");

    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This "answer" contains further information to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77913378/1505939).

Changing to `builder.Services.AddAuthorization();` removed the forced login that happened prior to any page being processed; however an effect of this was that a non-logged-in user can view any page in the application.  Each page is responsible for having `<NotAuthorized>` sections and so on.

To ensure non-logged-in users can only view one specific signin page, avoiding any chance of a security issue if I omitted authorization checks from each specific page, I also made the following changes:

- add `@attribute [Authorize]` to `_Imports.razor`, this makes all pages check for authorization and select the `<NotAuthorized>` block if present.
- add `<NotAuthorized>` section inside the `<AuthorizeRouteView>` in `App.razor`, which displays a message "Please log in using the above link" (my application shows a Log In link in the top bar of main layout). The login link is `<a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn">Log in</a>`.

It did not work to have `@attribute [Authorize]` in `MainLayout.razor`; the directive appeared to be ignored.

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/65743092/1505939
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/65119398/1505939  (how to redirect the default "Signed Out" page)