# Default URL "/" in always redirect to authentication in ASP.NET Core application with OIDC

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-entra-id

I have an application setup to use the Microsoft.Identity.Web package for OIDC authentication with Azure AD.

The configuration is:

```
  services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options => {
       configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
   });
```

and

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
  name: "default",
  pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

However when the application loads and the browser navigates to https://localhost:1524/ I am automatically redirect to Azure AD Login, despite the fact that the HomeController has AllowAnnonymous.

If I go the the HomeController explicitly, i.e. https://localhost:1542/home/index, then the page loads without authentication.

Why is the default URL causing authentication to kick in?

I am expecting the default route to load without redirecting to Azure AD

Comment: I am able to redirect to `HomeController` without any authentication even from Default URL `https://localhost:7114/`. [Image](https://i.imgur.com/wjwq9yK.png)

Comment: Do you have `AuthorizationPolicyBuilder` filter in your `Program.cs` file? Please share your complete `Program.cs` file code.

Comment: I had a policy builder but I removed it, it was originally 

 var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
     .Build();

Comment: Yes..this is must

Comment: Once try from ur end by adding that code

Comment: I asked a similar question a few days ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77910237/blazor-one-page-without-authentication  , maybe the answers will help you

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the default URL causing authentication to kick in? I am
> expecting the default route to load without redirecting to Azure AD

It would be great if you could share your controller as well. According to your scenario as you've called `app.UseAuthentication()` and `app.UseAuthorization()` in your program.cs code, the application goes through the authentication and authorization pipeline before reaching the controller.

If your `HomeController.Index` action doesn't explicitly specify any authorization requirements (like `[AllowAnonymous]`), the default behavior kicks in, which is to check for authenticated users based on the configured authentication scheme (in this case, Azure AD).

In order to resolve your issue, you could follow either way as following:

If your controller doesn't has `[AllowAnonymous]` annotation, you could use that.

Another way could be using of specific route exclusion for the default route in your authentication configuration. You can achieve this by modifying your `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` options to specify a route pattern to exclude from authentication. So you can do as following:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        options.ExcludedPaths.Add("/");
    });
```

**Note:** Keep in mind, by adding `options.ExcludedPaths.Add("/");`, you're telling the authentication middleware to skip authentication for requests to the root path ("/")

In addition, using [authorizaton policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-8.0) which you have removed, can also help to fixed that. In that scenario, you could modify your policy like below:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAnonymous", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AllowAnonymousRequirement()));
});

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { policy = "AllowAnonymous" });
```

**Note:** With above modification index action will instruct the authorization middleware to skip checking for authentication for this specific action, allowing anonymous access. Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-8.0) if you want to study more.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately ExcludePaths isn't an option I have. The HomeController has  the AllowAnnonymous attribute

Comment: In that scenario its better to consider policy  based approach and implementation.